Homotopy between posets
This is entirely a new area for me and I apologise in advance if the questions are silly.
In Quillen's paper "Homotopy properties of the posets of non-trivial $p$-subgroup of a group" (see here) (pages 114-116), the concept of a local coefficient system on a poset $X$ is defined as a functor $F: X \to \mathbf{Ab}$, where $\mathbf{Ab}$ is the category of abelian groups, with the additional condition that for any pair $x \leq y$ in $X$, there is an isomorphism between the groups $F(x)$ and $F(y)$.
In the same paper at page 115, it is mentioned that given a functor $F: X \to \mathbf{Ab}$, the homology $H_*(X, F)$ is defined as the homology of the chain complex $C_*(X, F)$, where the $p$-chains $C_p(X, F)$ are given by:
$$
C_p(X, F) = \bigoplus F(x_0),
$$
with the sum taken over all $p$-simplices of $X$ (i.e., chains of the form $x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_p$) and the differential defined in the usual way.
This definition of homology is not restricted to the local coefficient systems of abelian groups, as the author does not explicitly mention this restriction or I don't know whether it is implicit.
My question is:

If $X$ is a contractible poset and $F: X \to \mathbf{Ab}$ is any functor (not necessarily a local coefficient system), can we conclude that $H_i(X, F) = 0$ for all $i > 0$?

(Note: If $F$ is a local coefficient system, the result follows from Proposition 7.8 in the paper).

In the proof of Proposition 7.8 (the paragraph right after the statement) author assumes that if $f:X\to Y$ (which is a map of posets) is a homotopy equivalence then $$f/y=\{x\in X~|~f(x)\leq y\}$$ is contractible for every $y\in Y$. I don't see why the fibers are contractible or without loss how can we assume that.

If $f: X\to Y$ be a map of posets, with Y contractible. Let $F: X\to Ab$ be the constant functor $\mathbb{Z}$. Is the functor $Y\to Ab$ defined by $y\mapsto H_i(f/y)$ a local coefficient system of abelian groups? this functor is defined in the same paper at page 115. For this functor is $H_i(Y, y\mapsto H_j(f/y))=0$ for $i>0$?


I apologise for writing many questions at the same time!


No. You are right that $H_i(X,F)$ can be defined for any functor (and is an interesting object to study), but it does not typically vanish for $i > 0$ and $X$ contractible.   E.g. take $X$ to a be a poset with three objects $a,b,c$ with $a \geq c, b \geq c$, and take $F$ so that $F(a) = F(b) = 0$ and $F(c) = \mathbb Z$.

The discussion after the statement of 7.8 contains a proof of 1.6 by verifying conditions (a) and (b) of 7.8. It is in the proof of 1.6 that Quillen makes the assumption (not in the proof of 7.8, which follows from Whitehead's theorem).



If $f: X\to Y$ be a map of posets, with Y contractible. Let $F: X\to Ab$ be the constant functor $\mathbb{Z}$. Is the functor $Y\to Ab$ defined by $y\mapsto H_i(f/y)$ a local coefficient system of abelian groups? this functor is defined in the same paper at page 115. For this functor is $H_i(Y, y\mapsto H_j(f/y))=0$ for $i>0$?
